# neighbor of compact set in product space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Let $A,B$ be two compact sets in topology space $X,Y$ respectively. If $W$ is a neighbor of $A\times B$ in product space $X\times Y$, then prove there exists a neighbor $U$ of $A$ in $X$, neighbor $V$ of $B$ in $Y$, such that $U\times V \subset W$.

My attempt: Since $W$ is open, I have tried to find $\left\{ X_{\alpha} \right\}, \left\{ Y_{\alpha} \right\}$ as topological base such that $W=\cup X_{\alpha}\times Y_{\alpha}$, then from $A\times B$ compact there exists finite covering, but don't know how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand how a subset A of a space X  can be in X when only pionts of X are in X.  Don't you mean A subset X?

Answer (score 1):

Fix any point $y\in B$. Since $(x,y)\in A\times B\subset W$ for any point $x\in A$, there exist open neighborhoods 
$x\in O_x\subset X$ and $y\in O_{y,x}\subset Y$ such that $O_x\times O_{y,x}\subset W$. Since $\{O_x:x\in A\}$ is an open cover of the set $A$, there exists a finite set $F_y\subset A$ such that $U_y=\bigcup\{O_x:x\in F_y\}\supset A$. Put $O_y=\bigcap\{O_{y,x}:x\in F_y\}$. Then $A\times\{y\}\subset U_y\times O_y\subset W$. Since $\{O_y:y\in B\}$ is an open cover of the set $B$, there exists a finite set $F\subset B$ such that $V=\bigcup\{O_y:y\in F\}\supset B$. Put $U=\bigcap\{U_y:y\in F\}$. Then
$A\times B\subset U\times V\subset \bigcap\{U_y\times O_y:y\in F\}\subset W$.